# Can't scroll while other tabs load pages with Chrome on mac

Tags: mac, google-chrome, website, javascript, macbook-pro

I'm currently using chrome 8.0.552.215 on my MacBook Pro 13" (I know it's not the ultimate machine, but it's not that slow).

While a page loads in another tab, I can't scroll the page I'm currently in, like it's freezing or something.

I don't think it was doing this before, but it's pretty annoying, since Google advanced that the browser use one thread per tab, it seems something is not working well...

I wonder if deactivating javascript would solve this...

Any idea ?

Comment: Same issue here on Windows 7, but it seems to only happen if the loading tab is on the same domain as the one I'm trying to scroll.

Comment: Same for me under Linux with Chromium 19.0.1084.52. IMHO, while another tab is loading, every tab in the same thread can't be scrolled. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue until today - it appears that for some reason my `Chrome` believed it should be in `Developer Mode` ...

Go to `Settings` --> `Extensions` and uncheck the `Developer Mode` option if it is set on your machine.

It should solve the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Does this problem happen every time another tab is loading and your current tab fail to scroll? If this happens intermittently, the issue could be due to system load. You can try:

- Disabling any Chrome extensions that you do not need
- Restart Chrome
- Browse in `Incognito` mode (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> or its equivalent in Mac). Extensions are disabled by default in Incognito

[Similar problems](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30189) that has been reported are not investigated if it only happens intermittently and cannot be reproduced.